# Where to store files uploaded by users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, authorization

Story: an user can upload private files (pdf's) like his Curriculum Vitae. he als needs to be able to view his uploaded files. I know a database would become slower, so i want to storage the files in a filesystem. But where should i store the files, so it is secure and other users cant reach it. Should i just create a directory in my Project/Solution or a directory outside my project. Or should i store it all in the WWWROOT. can someone give me advice?

I have an ASP.NET CORE mvc application. i want to store the filename and path in the database. the uploaded file needs to be stored in the filesystem.

Comment: This is based on an opinion, but you can store it in wwwroot, or some cloud storage.

Comment: Its better to save the files outside wwwroot. You can use a network path also which is not accessible to other users

Comment: Where are you hosting your website? AWS? Google Could? Azure?

Comment: @AA Why is it better to save it outside the wwwroot? is the wwwroot accasible by everyone?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini the asp.net mvc application is not hosted yet. some company will do the hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in wwwroot and let everyone access it or custom folder.

Consider security concern you can check user role or add some middleware to limit user access to that folder.

or use

[Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0#static-file-authorization)

> The Static File Middleware doesn't provide authorization checks. Any
>   files served by it, including those under wwwroot, are publicly
>   accessible. To serve files based on authorization:
>
> Store them outside of wwwroot and any directory accessible to the
>   Static File Middleware.
>
> Serve them via an action method to which authorization is applied.
>   Return a FileResult object

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult BannerImage()
{
    var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                            "MyStaticFiles", "images", "banner1.svg");

    return PhysicalFile(file, "image/svg+xml");
}
```

Comment: Storing files under website root (www) is a simple solution, but would cause problem down the road. For example, how would synchronize this folder when you have 2 web-servers running behind a load balancer? It also has a negative impact on performance, as website is responsible for serving the files.

Comment: Yes. In this case we should use cloud provider like azure blob storage

Comment: Wait so i should choose a directory outside the wwwroot?

Comment: It depend on what you need but as I can see right now you are only use wwwroot to store the file so I think you can use wwwroot for now.

Comment: I agree, for DEV environment, you can get away with wwwroot, but when you move to production you probably want to use the storage system provided from the hosting provider.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Should i store the files in the project directory or outside the project directory for production

Comment: As I said when you move to production, you might have more than 1 web servers running behind a load balancer. If you put the folder in your project directory (which will go to wwwroot) then each server will have its own copy of the folder... how do you want to sync these 2 folders? For Production you need an external storage which is automatically backed up and both web servers can access. As an example if you are using AWS to host your website, you can store the files in S3 bucket and serve them from AWS CloudFront...